# stratified random sampling with different ratios for group variables in R

Tags: r, random

I made a simple example that illustrates what I want to achieve.
Lets say I have this data frame:

```
x <- data.frame(a=1:10,b = factor(c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b")),
            gender = factor(c("boy","girl","boy","girl","girl","boy","boy","boy","girl","boy")))
```

The data frame has 10 observations. 40% girls, 60% boys. 50% a, 50% b.

I want to be able to form a random sample that maintains the ratios of the selected key variables in the sample, so in this case I want that in my sample the ratio of girls will be 40% and of boys will be 60%, and also a 50%, and b 50%.
How can I do that? The examples I found on the internet all assume a common ratio for all the variables, its not good for my purposes.
Thanks!

Comment: If you have a lot of data, a large sample [ought to be around those ratios anyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_toward_the_mean), no?

Comment: @Jimbou yes but nothing assures me that the other variables will get sampled with the correct proportions

Comment: don't understand. why not using `data.frame(a=1:10, b=sample(c("a", "b"), 10,replace = T, prob = c(0.5,0.5)),
           gender=sample(c("girl", "boy"), 10,replace = T, prob = c(0.4,0.6)))`

Comment: @Jimbou Eventually I have a big data frame with unique ID's and each ID has all its features. My goal is to sample `n` ID's preserving the ratios of certain features that is present in the original table. In this simple example I have made - the IDs are in variable `a`

Comment: The ratios should be preserved when n is high enough. Simply try `x[sample(1:nrow(x, n, F),]` it and calculate the ratios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments for a large enough sample the ratios in the sub-samples should be similar. For smaller data sets here is an approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
```

create a group that is an interaction of the two factors and split according to that. Since your sample is very small this can not produce the exact proportion (no method can):

```
x %>%
  select(b, gender) %>%
  group_by(b, gender) %>%
  group_indices() -> ind

split1 <- createDataPartition(as.factor(ind), p = 0.5)[[1]]

table(x[split1,2])
#output
a b 
2 2 

table(x[split1,3])
#output
 boy girl 
   3    1
```

with twice as big data set:

```
x <- rbind(x, x)

x %>%
  select(b, gender) %>%
  group_by(b, gender) %>%
  group_indices() -> ind

split1 <- createDataPartition(as.factor(ind), p = 0.5)[[1]]

table(x[split1,2])
#output
a b 
5 5 

table(x[split1,3])
#output
 boy girl 
   6    4
```

try other ratio:

```
split1 <- createDataPartition(as.factor(ind), p = 0.7)[[1]]

table(x[split1,2])
#output
a b 
8 8 

table(x[split1,3])
#output
 boy girl 
   9    7
```

Comment: Thanks! You were all right - the ratios are preserved in a good enough way when `n` is sufficiently large (in my case it is 5000 out of 1.5 Million)